# Set AppId and AppSecret in code using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using Facebook C# SDK to setup Facebook Authentication in my MVC application. The SDK requires the appId and appSecret to be stored in the Facebook Settings section in the web config. I would like to store my appId and appKey somewhere else. is there a way to set these values in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the values when creating a new FacebookClient object

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="FacebookClient"/> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="appId">
/// The app id.
/// </param>
/// <param name="appSecret">
/// The app secret.
/// </param>
public FacebookClient(string appId, string appSecret) : this(string.Concat(appId, "|", appSecret))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of coding standards (as well as ease of use) I would implement the `IFacebookApplication` interface. You can then pass an instance of this into the `FacebookClient` constructor.